# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest-framework' with virtualenv and python3.7.4

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm going though this tutorial: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework

I make all of the changes, but when I get to the `runserver` part, I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest-framework'` error..

```
| => ./manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/maione/urls.py", line 36, in <module>
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest-framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione/env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest-framework'

^C(env) ________________________________________________________________________________
| /Volumes/thunderb/attic/Projects/VS/maione @ TRUHQWSOSX3 (agraf) 
| => python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep  7 2019, 18:27:02) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rest_framework as rf
>>> dir(rf)
['HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING', 'ISO_8601', 'RemovedInDRF311Warning', 'RemovedInDRF312Warning', 'VERSION', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__title__', '__version__', 'default_app_config']
>>>
```

settings.py installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

For some reason, I can not get it to run - I keep getting the above error. I've tried installing and reinstalling `python`, `virtualenv` and trying different directories and env's. No matter what I do, I keep getting this error. I've `pip install djangorestframework` probably 10 times trying to get this to work.

On OSX trying out VS Code.

I assumed that by running `pip install djangorestframework` that that satisfied dependencies. Do I also need the `django-rest-framework` folder? If so, do I put the `projectfolder` folder inside of it? Right now, it looks like:

```
|-env/
|-example/ (project folder)
|-db.sqlite3
|-manage.py
```

do I also need the `django-rest-framework/` in there? I assumed it lived in env/.../site-packages folder?

Please, any ideas where I'm going wrong or suggestions to narrow down the issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `urls.py` file, replace:

```py
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest-framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

by:

```py
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

With an underscore, not a dash on `rest_framework`. The stack trace pointed you the faulty line actually :)